# Do I have an ext4 partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ext4, btrfs

I ran the command `file -sL /dev/sda*`, and out of nine drives, the first part of the output of the seventh one says `/dev/sda7: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data`.

Just to make sure, does this mean I have an ext4 partition and not a btrfs one?

Comment: ext4 is the journaling file system for Ubuntu and most of other Linux distros, so it is normal to have ext4 partitions.

Comment: You can also run `df -hT` (`T` being the important switch) so see the filesystem type.